# how to redirect External domain to existing sub domain with same website content

Tags: .htaccess

**I want to redirect the subdomain to an external domain with the same website content**

```
  cblog.domain.com ->      newdomain.com
  cblog.domain.com/aboutus ->      newdomain.com/aboutus
  cblog.domain.com/profile ->      newdomain.com/profile
```

**This is htacsess code**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cblog\domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

**I can redirect to newdomain.com with this code but am not able to  access same web site content**

Please help me

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot "access the same web site content"?   Haven't you set the web site up on the new domain name yet?  If not, you don't want to redirect until you have done that.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code contains issues, but those are most likely just typos here on SO. If it redirects, then what is the actual issue you face now?